# How to match a string, but only if the same string has not already been matched with or without dashes?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a case I'm trying to match using regular expressions.

My current expression will match a string in a certain format with or without dashes. I would like to add it to match only if the string has not been matched before, with or without the dashes. For example, take the following cases:

```
1.  1234-56-789-5555
2.  1234567895555
3.  0000-99-888-3333
4.  1111223334444
```

If the four examples above appeared in this same order in a list, document, whatever, I would want to only capture (1, 3, 4). I want to skip #2 since it was already captured by #1, but with the dashes. If #2 had of come first, I would have wanted to similarly skip #1.

Here's the current expression I'm using:

`\d\d\d\d-*\d\d-*\d\d\d-*\d\d\d\d`

I tried to read up on look behinds (I'm fairly inexperienced with Regex) but I only really understand that a look behind only checks if certain text is matched previously. I'm not sure if what I want can be combined with this; I only see how to check for specific text, not for the current value with/without dashes.

I'm currently doing this with C# logic, but am trying to see if it can be done purely in Regex. If it can't be done, that's fine; I'm just trying to beef up my Regex knowledge in this case.

Is this possible -- how can I accomplish this?

Comment: You'll need some `C#` logic for this.  It could be as easy as removing all dashes from your strings, and grabbing unique ones, skipping Regex altogether.  If that is your actual data

Comment: What are the other match criteria and restrictions?
Maybe you can avoid regex all together.
As for skipping already matched items, you would only need to strip out the dashes in code and check if your existing collection already contains that string, add it if not.

Comment: I'm already using C# logic to check this -- just wondered if it could be done purely using Regex.

Comment: You can strip dashes of course when matching, but you can't merely in a single regex instruct it to not match strings because they were already matched earlier in the document, dashes or not.

Comment: +1 to what irreal said...No matter what, you will need to compare any new string to those existing in the collection to see if one already exists

Comment: Hate to be so negative, but regexs can be poisonous, especially in c#. I've had only slightly complicated ones with unexpected but not unreasonable input take down a whole website. So I would say why? Why attempt this, even for learning, when this is so easily achieved with standard imperative logic?

Comment: Instead of using regex to see if the format matches, use those regex expressions to sort of mask the fields so only input in those patterns are allowed to be entered by the user. Then you can just simply revome the '-' dashes and compare the string to those already in the collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to obtain just the first occurrence of each number (answering *I want to skip #2 since it was already captured by #1, but with the dashes*), you need a negative look-behind with a `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` and `RegexOptions.Singleline` options:

```
(?<!\b\1-?\2-?\3-?\4\b.*)\b(\d{4})-?(\d{2})-?(\d{3})-?(\d{4})\b
```

The `\b(\d{4})-?(\d{2})-?(\d{3})-?(\d{4})\b` subpattern is the number with capture groups to check for their presence regardless of the hyphens earlier in the string.

The `(?<!\b\1-?\2-?\3-?\4\b.*)` subpattern look-behind is checking if we have no other occurrences of the same string.

Tested at [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester) and in Expresso:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this without using regex.. but if you still want to use regex for this purpose.. you can use the following to match:

```
(?<=((\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})).*?)\2\3\4\5
```

And replace with `''` (empty string)

Explanation:

- This will match all those **digits without dashes** which are already captured by **digits with dashes**

So, in your `1,2,3 and 4`.. instead of matching `1,3 and 4` types it matches type `2`.. and you can replace it with `''` (nothing) and you remain with `1,3, and 4`

See [demo here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D((%5Cd%7B4%7D)-(%5Cd%7B2%7D)-(%5Cd%7B3%7D)-(%5Cd%7B4%7D)).*%3F)%5C2%5C3%5C4%5C5&i=1234-56-789-5555%0D%0A1234567895555%0D%0A0000-99-888-3333%0D%0A1111223334444&o=s)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to do exactly what you want..

```
((?<=((\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})).*?)(?!\3\4\5\6)\d{13})|(((?<=((\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{4})).*?)(?!\10-\11-\12-\13)((\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{3})-(\d{4}))))
```

Explanation:

- `((?<=((\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})).*?)(?!\3\4\5\6)\d{13})` match all those `\d{13}` which are not previously occurred with dashes in between them (this excludes strings of type `2` in your case)
- `((\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{3})-(\d{4}))` and match all of this pattern

Matches `1, 3 and 4` in your case.

See [DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=((%3f%3c%3d((%5cd%7b4%7d)-(%5cd%7b2%7d)-(%5cd%7b3%7d)-(%5cd%7b4%7d)).*%3f)(%3f!%5c3%5c4%5c5%5c6)%5cd%7b13%7d)%7c(((%3f%3c%3d((%5cd%7b4%7d)(%5cd%7b2%7d)(%5cd%7b3%7d)(%5cd%7b4%7d)).*%3f)(%3f!%5c10-%5c11-%5c12-%5c13)((%5cd%7b4%7d)-(%5cd%7b2%7d)-(%5cd%7b3%7d)-(%5cd%7b4%7d))))&i=0000-99-888-3333%0d%0a1234567895555%0d%0a1234-56-789-5555%0d%0a1234567895555%0d%0a0000-99-888-3333%0d%0a1111223334444%0d%0a0000998883333%0d%0a%0d%0a%0d%0a&o=s)

Comment: @stribizhev thanks for pointing out the mistake.. i believe it can be done using regex (might be wrong).. please check the updated regex.. :)